# Displaying text after space in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have my website connected to a database with MySQL and I am echoing out the data but it doesn't display information after a space. E.g. in the database 'Hello there' would just be 'Hello'.

I know this is quite a common question asked but I just couldn't get mine working. An example is this:

```
County: <input type = "text" name = "county" value = <?php echo $row["county"]; ?>> <br><br>
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces around the `=`?

Comment: use `County: <input type = "text" name = "county" value = "<?php echo $row["county"]; ?>"> <br><br>`

Comment: @DWard, you might already have tried this, but just in case, a good thing to try when you have problems like this is to "View source" on the output page and look at the HTML to see if it looks right. In this case I think it would look like this and the problem would be easier to spot: `County: <input type = "text" name = "county" value = Hello there> <br><br`. Good luck!

Comment: @leoger Ok thanks I will try that next time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your [HTML attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) value. Without it the first word is considered the value and everything else is considered a new HTML attribute.

```
County: <input type = "text" name = "county" value = <?php echo $row["county"]; ?>> <br><br>
```

Should be:

```
County: <input type = "text" name = "county" value = "<?php echo $row["county"]; ?>"> <br><br>
                                                   //^                             ^
```